# Java Slot machine college project

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I'm making a slot machine for a college project. There are loads and loads of similar projects talked about online however the requirements for my project are slightly different. Here is my task:

1. The player starts with £1 credit, with each go costing 20 p.
2. If the Fruit Machine “rolls” two of the same symbol, the user wins 50 p.
3. The player wins £1 for three of the same and £5 for 3 Bells.
4. The player loses £1 if two skulls are rolled and all of his/her money if three skulls are rolled.
5. The player can choose to quit with the winnings after each roll or keep playing until there is no money left.

What I've come up with so far is this:

```
for ( int runCount = 1; runCount <= 3; runCount ++ ) {

        int symIndex = r.nextInt(6);

        if (symIndex == 0) {
            symbol = "cherry";
        } else if (symIndex == 1){
            symbol = "orange";
        } else if (symIndex == 2){
            symbol = "lemon";
        } else if (symIndex == 3){
            symbol = "bell";
        } else if (symIndex == 4){
            symbol = "star";
        } else if (symIndex == 5){
            symbol = "skull";
        }

        if (runCount == 1){
            reel1 = symbol;
        } else if ( runCount == 2 ){
            reel2 = symbol;
        } else if ( runCount == 3 ){
            reel3 = symbol;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(reel1 + "  " + reel2 + "  " + reel3);
```

Which is great and spits out 3 random symbols but what is I need is a way is for it to somehow treat the bell and skull symbols differently. There must be an easier way than write out every possible combination in an if statement. In all the other projects I've seen the prize if statements have looked something like this

```
if (reel1 == reel2 && reel1 == reel3 && reel2 == reel3)
System.out.println("You have won!");
```

Or something about that etc etc. But if I do it this way it's not defining the actual symbol but just storing it in one of the reel variables so I can't make if statements for those specific outcomes.

Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated. Even if you could just tell me how to phrase my question properly so I could search it would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed things a little. Rather than storing 3 unique fields `reel1`, `reel2` and `reel3` you can re-use the counter variable you're using to control the for-loop to place the chosen symbols into an array. Note: you need to start the counter at 0, but this makes little/no difference.

```java
    private static final String CHERRY = "cherry";
    private static final String ORANGE = "orange";
    private static final String LEMON = "lemon";
    private static final String BELL = "bell";
    private static final String STAR = "star";
    private static final String SKULL = "skull";
    private static final Random random = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] symbols = new String[3];
        pickRandomSymbolsForReels(symbols);
        displayReels(symbols);
        Map<String, Integer> symbolCounts = new HashMap<>();
        checkResults(symbols, symbolCounts);
        displayResults(symbolCounts);
    }

    private static void checkResults(String[] symbols, Map<String, Integer> symbolCounts) {
        // for each symbol
        // if (symbolCounts.get(symbol) != null) {
        //      symbolCounts.put(symbol, 1);
        // } else {
        //      int incrementedValue = symbolCounts.get(symbol) + 1;
        //      symbolCounts.put(symbol, incrementedValue);
        // }
    }

    private static String[] pickRandomSymbolsForReels(String[] symbols) {
        for (int reelIndex = 0; reelIndex < symbols.length; reelIndex++) {
            int choice = random.nextInt(6);
            switch (choice) {
                case 0:
                    symbols[reelIndex] = CHERRY;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    symbols[reelIndex] = ORANGE;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    symbols[reelIndex] = LEMON;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    symbols[reelIndex] = BELL;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    symbols[reelIndex] = STAR;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    symbols[reelIndex] = SKULL;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return symbols;
    }

    private static void displayReels(String[] symbols) {
        for (String symbol : symbols) {
            System.out.print(symbol + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static void displayResults(Map<String, Integer> symbolCounts) {
        /**
         * Here you'll need to understand the logic of various events.
         * e.g
         * 3 skulls - instantly lose all credit - game over
         * 2 skulls - decreaseBalance(1.00)
         * 3 Bells - increaseBalance(amount)
         * 3 of any other symbol - increaseBalance(amount)
         * 2 of any thing else - increaseBalance(amount)
         * .. etc
         */
        // if (hasThreeSkulls(symbolCounts.get(SKULL)) {
        //   gameOver();
        // } else if (hasTwoSkulls(symbolCounts.get(SKULL)) {
        //   decreaseBalance(100) // note when working with money, store pence amount only and display the value as pounds and pence.. otherwise you'll have issues
        // } etc ..
    }
```

Next gather the stats from the reels (counts of the symbols of interest). Finally check the stats for winning/losing results. This will be a bunch of `if, else-if` statements.

Comment: This is fantastic! I can't thank you enough. I'm off to go and learn about "switch" and case now

Comment: Updated with some more info - should be easy if you follow this. You'll notice I do not store "state" that changes as a class variable but rather pass the mutating objects around. This should make working with the logic easier and is known as "stateless" - so makes the code more flexible for future use.